# coredata multithread without concurrency

Tags: iphone, multithreading, core-data

I need to update a lot of objects in a coredata database.
I perform this update in a separate thread to avoid blocking user interface and display a simple HUD during this operation.
Can i have some trouble of concourrency?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just beware that [coredata](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) isn't thread save.

Possible solution as provided by Apple:

> 1. Create a separate managed object context for each thread and share a
>      single persistent store coordinator. This is the
>      typically-recommended approach.
> 2. Create a separate managed object context and persistent store
>      coordinator for each thread. This approach provides for greater
>      concurrency at the expense of greater complexity (particularly if
>      you need to communicate changes between different contexts) and
>      increased memory usage.

If used the first option multiple times when updating the model from a background thread. It seems to work.